# How can I pad numbers with leading zeroes using the seq command?

Tags: text-processing, seq

I had to generate a text file for a given range of numbers. As usual I had to use `seq range_start range_end  > text_file.txt` to put it in a text file.

I gave the seq range where the starting point was `01700` and the ending point was `01800`. I know it's useless to have 0 before the number but in my case it was important. The file generated had lines like `1700`, `1701` ... `1800`. But there was no `0` before the numbers as I put in the command.

How am I supposed to put 0 before every line in the file? Or, is there any way to generate the text with 0 in it before every line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `seq -w` to keep consistent output width.

`seq -w 01700 01800` will output 01700, 01701 etc.

As always, `man seq` should be your starting point when wondering about `seq`. Unix manpages are there for a reason, and very often solve such questions up front.